# Lambda SDK Calls No Response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am trying to do a pretty simple "hello world" in AWS Lambda.  I tried a few services that only call the AWS SDK and just try to read.  My callback never gets called.  I have to be missing something.  Any help appreciated!

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };

    var s3 = new AWS.S3(); // confirmed this is not null
    s3.listBuckets({}, function(err, data) {
           // never reaches here!
           if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    });

    return response;
};
```

I did create a role this lambda is using that has S3 access.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that because I chose the Node 8.x runtime, I needed to use one of those async constructs.   This worked...

```
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
let s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    return await s3.listBuckets().promise() ;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a synchronization problem.

Your `return response` code is executed before your callback is invoked.

you'll have to put your return statement inside your callback or use [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Returning inside your callback:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
  };

  var s3 = new AWS.S3();
  s3.listBuckets({}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack);
      return {
        statusCode: 500,
        message: 'some error'
      }
    }
    return response
  });
}
```

Using async/await:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200
  };

  var s3 = new AWS.S3();
  await s3.listBuckets().promise();
  return response;
}
```

I'd go with the async/await approach as it's much cleaner and more readable. It's also easier to work with promises than with callbacks.

**EDIT**: The OP claimed it didn't work. So I have decided to test it on my own. The above code works, with a very small change just to add the listed buckets to the response. Here's the final code:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200
  };

  var s3 = new AWS.S3();
  const buckets = await s3.listBuckets().promise();
  response.body = JSON.stringify(buckets);
  return response;
}
```

And here's the output in CloudWatch Logs:

[image]

Comment: I tried this just now and get a null instead of a response.  I also had tried to wrap the request in a Promise and it didn't wait in that case either.

Comment: where exactly do you get a null? I'll test it in the meantime

Comment: I have edited my answer with the outputs. The code I showed works properly

Comment: You are right.  It does not work without the `await` statement as I posted also.